# Long loading operation on opening an xml layout on latest ADT

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

In latest ADT bundle when I try to open an xml layout editor, it opens and then this message appears:

> The rendering target (Android 4.4.2) is still loading.
>
> The layout will refresh automatically once the process is finished.

Also most of the operations in eclipse are taking long time,like renaming a resource and I don't think that is somehow related to my PC configuration.

I'm using latest JDK , what should i do? or it's a bug in android developing tools?

Comment: It seems rare, but I have similar problems with the latest ADT also, I have recently updated it and these problems started (they were not there before with the older version).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your Android SDK and ADT have the exact same version. For example, if you have Android SDK v22.6.2 installed, you must also have ADT v22.6.2 installed.

Also, Java JDK 1.6.45 is the latest compatible version for Android. JDK 7 is not yet supported.

FYI: Android SDK v22.6.1 and ADT v22.6.1 are buggy. You should upgrade both to v22.6.2.