# Android - The rendering target is still loading

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, adt, android-sdk-tools

I am using **Eclipse 4.2.1** to build an Android application, and recently I upgraded my Eclipse ADT. Now I have **ADT 23.0.6.** After an upgrade, I noticed that I cannot view my XML layouts anymore. There is a message "**The rendering target (Android 5.0.1) is still loading. The layout will refresh automatically once the process is finished.**" and it never goes away. I have read on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22397412/long-loading-operation-on-opening-an-xml-layout-on-latest-adt) that it's because my Android SDK and ADT are of different versions. Indeed, my Android SDK is 24.1.2 . However, there is no ADT version 24.1.2.    ADT 23.0.6 is the most recent version. So, is it true that the reason for my XML layout file not loading is that I have different versions of ADT & SDK? What should I do?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just change the 21 to 17 beside PayrollActivity in snapshot so that u can view xml 
as your ADT is latest one xml automatically loading 5.0.1

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I just uninstall ADT plugin and reinstall. Resolved my problem and it's working.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue.

Uninstall ADT from Eclipse *`(Help>About Eclipse>Installed Details>Un-install)`* and reinstall using `Help>Install New Software>` ADT - [Android eclipse](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse)

Can now place widgets from design palate in to my activity layout like before.